# Tabula-py: reading tables from a pdf that contains form fields

Tags: python, pdf-scraping, tabula-py

I'm trying to read a pdf that contains multiple tables that have form fields for ticks/checkmarks free text, numbers, dropdown selections etc.

Unfortunately the dataframes that are returned don't render the information contained in the pdf fields.

Does anyone know whether it is possible to extract that information as well?

Comment: What is the code that you are using, and what is the problematic output? Please add that detail, as much as possible.

Comment: I'm trying to get data from tabpy using: `table = tabula.read_pdf(file, pages='all')   ` then I access the list elements to the get the dataframes. the problem is that the data from the tables is extracted but some table cells contain data in "input form elements". That data is not being extracted. Any ideas? :-)